# I was learning SHM and I came across equation $k = mw^2$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

I tried searching for proofs here and there but couldn't find.. Some people used $a= w^2 x$ to prove this.. But how do you prove that?

Comment: The picture is not legible. Please write out specifically what your question is, and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: My question is what's the derivation of k = mw^2 or what's the derivation of a = w^2x

Comment: And I thought that $g=\ell \omega^2$.  :)

Comment: @yashgabra Those are two different questions. Plus you haven't given a specific context. We can read between the lines, but that's not a good way to pose a question. You should state what the specific physical system is.  Also, the character is omega, $\omega$ not $w$.

Answer (score 3):

Newton's second law states the force on a system is proportional to its acceleration. For linear restoring force $-kx$, we have

$$F = ma$$
$$ -kx = m\ddot{x}$$

where $\ddot{x}$ is the second time-derivative of position, i.e. acceleration. Then you have

$$ \ddot{x} = a = -\frac{k}{m}x = -\omega^2 x$$

where we define $\omega = \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$.

Comment: Is omega another constant in this and not angular frequency?

Comment: $\omega$ is the angular frequency, but for a simple harmonic oscillator, that happens to be a constant value.

Answer (score 1):

In Zhutchens1's force equation, the second derivative of x is a negative constant times x.  The simplest solution for this differential equation is x = sin(ωt + φ)  where ω is the angular frequency and  φ depends on when you start the clock.  If you put this function for x into the equation, you find that $ω^2$ = k/m.

Answer (score 0):

I think what is bothering you is how did we end here:
$$a=-\omega^2 x$$
form here:
$$a=-(k/m) x$$

This is matter more of Mathematics than Physics. In mathematics, the standard solution of the below differential equation:
$$\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}= - p^2 y\tag1$$
is this:
$$y= C_1\sin(px + C_2)$$where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are arbitrary constants.

In Physics, so we assign the value $\omega=k/m$ on our own "arbitrarily". And further obtain the solution:
$$y= A \sin(\omega t + \phi)$$
where A and $\phi$ are arbitrary constants. It just so happens that we physically interpret A as amplitude and $\phi$ as initial phase.

---

Now if you want the solution of equation (1) , that was nothing to do with Physics. Try referring to a Mathematics text for the same.

Comment: Having two $k$'s, with $k=mk^2$, is not great for clarity

Comment: It's not an arbitrary assignment. In fact, what you call $k^2$ is, in the careful physics analysis, $k/m$ for a spring-mass oscillator system.

Comment: @BillN I used the word "arbitrarily" in quotes for the same purpose. Are you suggesting me to edit my terminology?

Comment: @fqq Point noted.

Comment: Please don't mess up with variables, try to make it lucid. Solve the differential equation to show the asker how it's derived without just writing it as a standard solution.